# Getting difference from two tables and deleting it in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing issue in writing the logic of a query that deletes data which are not existing in either of the 2 tables.

For example, I have a tables "Stage" and "Parent". I am using composite primary keys to uniquely identity records(multiple primary keys).

Stage structure and Data

```
S_Column1(Primary) | PRIDATA1 | PRIDATA4
S_Column2(Primary) | PRIDATA2 | PRIDATA5
S_Column3(Primary) | PRIDATA3 | PRIDATA6
S_Column4          | DJUC     | JDNC
S_Column5          | DSSDC    | JDDOS
```

Parent structure and Data

```
P_Column1(Primary) | PRIDATA1 | PRIDATA4 | PRIDATA7
P_Column2(Primary) | PRIDATA2 | PRIDATA5 | PRIDATA8
P_Column3(Primary) | PRIDATA3 | PRIDATA6 | PRIDATA9
P_Column4          | DJUC     | JDNC     | FFED
P_Column5          | DSSDC    | JDDOS    | NHUY
```

The above is just a sample of structure and data of two tables. 
So basically what I want to do is write a query to delete the row that have 
`PRIDATA7 PRIDATA8` and `PRIDATA9` as primary key because their entries are not present in STAGE TABLE.

I am not skilled, but I know I need to find out matching data using `JOIN` and delete the rest of the data from PARENT TABLE whose entries aren't present in STAGE TABLE

PS: I will be using this in a Trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not exists

```
delete from parent
where not exists (
   select 1 
   from stage s 
   where s.S_Column1 = parent.S_Column1 and s.S_Column2 = parent.S_Column2 and s.S_Column3 = parent.S_Column3)
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Can you please explain me, whats this '1'? Select 1?

Comment: Exists returns no data only boolean true/false. So any data in Select will do. Select 1 just saves a bit of unnecesarry work .

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the EXCEPT operator. 
Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188055(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Yes i thought of it, but I can only select and display it. How can I delete those data using EXCEPT?

Comment: You can make a temp table with data to delete and then delete from parent table using where clause (for example - where column in (select something from #something)